# Can a texture be updated in background thread but printed in foreground thread?

Tags: android, opengl-es, webrtc, opengl-es-2.0

In webRTC, in `SurfaceTextureHelper` the `surfaceTexture` (with handle the creation/update of the openGL texture) is created inside a background thread:

```
final HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread(threadName);
thread.start();
```

an inside this newly created thread we do

```
oesTextureId = GlUtil.generateTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(oesTextureId);
```

The problem is that the `OnFrameAvailableListener` of the `surfacetexture` will be called in the thread where the `surfacetexture` was created (seam logical). My problem is that all the painting of my app are done in the **main UI thread** (and I can not change this), so here I end up by something where the texture will be updated in background thread (texture of `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`) but will be print on the foreground thread.

Is it possible that it's will work ? textureID never change, just the content of the texture get updated in the bakcground thread